# How to insert elements to the end of a growing list using slice in python

Tags: python, list, slice

I know there are other methods like extend but i want to know if it is possible:

```
lt = ['p','y','t','h','o','n']
```

after using slice

```
 ['p','y','t','h','o','n','g','o']
```

My list is always growing and i need to use slice for an specific reason.

Comment: What do you mean as a growing list?

Comment: `lt + list('go')`

Comment: I am adding elements to my list, right now I am using extend to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `numpy` with `np.r_` ([read the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html))

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array(['p','y','t','h','o','n'])
arr2 = np.array(['g','o'])

combined_arr = np.r_[arr1, arr2]
>>> array(['p','y','t','h','o','n','g','o'])
```